# Compare the numbers in base $3$

Tags: ternary-expansion

Let $x,y\in\ [0,1]$ a real numbers. Suppose that $$x=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{a_n}{3^n},\quad y=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{b_n}{3^n},\;a_n,b_n\in\{0,1,2\}$$
they are their ternary expansions.

*Suppose we know only the ternary expressions and not actually the real number they represent.*

> **Question** Can I compare $x$ and $y$ working exclusively in base 3? Or rather, how can I determine if $x\le y$ or $y\le x$?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "compare"

Comment: @Klangen That is to say if $x\le y$ or $y\le x$.

Comment: Do you know the rule that defines the $a_n$ and $b_n$?

Comment: You know how to compare two numbers given their decimal expansions - the same thing obviously works for ternary expansions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, except for one small problem : some numbers have TWO different ternary developments.

Simple rule : if $a_n=b_n$ for all $n<n_0$, and $a_{n_0}<b_{n_0}$, then $x\le y$.

They can still be the same if $a_{n_0}=b_{n_0}-1$, and $a_n=2$ and $b_n=0$ for all $n>n_0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But if I already know that $x\le y$ can I say about $a_n$ and $b_n$?

Comment: Just what I said above : consider the development of $y-x$ : if it is greater than $3^{-n_0}$, then some $a_n$ is strictly smaller then $b_n$ for $n\le n_0$.

Comment: For example $\frac{1}{3}=0,00\overline{2}_3$ and $1/3=0,0\overline{1}_3$, what can I say about the digits of the  numbers that are less than $1/3$?

Comment: $\frac13=0,1_3$, or $0,0\overline1_3$. If $x<\frac13$, consider the development of $\frac13-x$ : it's a strictly positive number, so it has to have some strictly positive coefficients. Consider the one with the smaller index.

Comment: Then if $x<\frac{1}{3}$, we can say with certainty that the first digit $a_1$ of $x$ is zero, if were $a_1=1$, then may be other digits other different from zero and then $x>\frac{1}{3}$ or $x=\frac{1}{3}$. Moreover if were $a_1=2$, then $x>\frac{1}{3}$. In any case we would get an absurdity. Quite right?